# django allauth not translating correctly

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Im using [django_allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) for user authentication and registration. My web app is being developed in spanish and all the libraries im using are being translated using this settings:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Hermosillo'

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#language-code
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#site-id
SITE_ID = 1

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-i18n
USE_I18N = True

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-l10n
USE_L10N = True

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-tz
USE_TZ = True
```

and all text inside my page is being translated except for *some* of the allauth messages, for example:

[image: allauth form]

all form text in this image is being translated by allauth templates. but when the user registers it shows translated text for some things but untranslated text for others, like the following paragraph:

[image: signup]

the most important part for me is the confirmation email which isnt being translated at all:

[image]

I have looked inside the allauth files and I have found that there is already a translation for the email template and all that stuff but it is not handling it correctly I think, is there any way I cant correct that on settings or some way to override that email generation template and provide my own?

Comment: how you double check your i18n locale `.po` file and have you checked the compiled files?

Comment: here: [screenshot](http://imgur.com/Xpftp9e). Does this help? @haifeng-zhang